# CSS Top Relative To Screen

Tags: html, css

I have a problem where I have multiple elements that match the background image's position. When the window size is changed(especially going very small) then the elements' "top" values don't stay constant. This small issue builds up and 10 elements later everything is totally wrong. Play around with the window size (try making it very small) to easily see the problem.

How can I fix this problem and keep them matching the background all the time?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                margin: 0;
            }
    
            div {
                min-width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;  
                background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/EX2L8y6.jpg");
                background-size: 100%, 100%;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                position: absolute;
            }
    
            .TheBtn {
                position: relative;
                background-color: red;
                opacity: 0.5;
                height: 4.4vw;
                width: 22.2vw;
                left: 19vw;
                top: 10.8vw;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <button class="TheBtn"></button>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: SO provides an HTML snippet editor which lets you execute your code directly, do not expect people to manually copy paste your code and then run experiments

Comment: I suggest you look into the CSS `position`-properties and see what they actually mean.

Comment: @Jesse de Bruijne What do you mean, position: fixed doesn't work either because my website can scroll, in which case the element scrolls with the user

Comment: use vh unit with top not vw

Comment: @Temani Afif Thanks for the idea but unfortunately that seems to work even less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set an element to relative it means that all of the child elements are relative to that parent. .TheBtn is set to relative but has no child elements. You need to set the div to relative as .TheBtn is a child of div, and the positioning of .TheBtn will be absolute in relation to the nearest parent element that is relative(the div). Here is the code I used to test:

```css
html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/EX2L8y6.jpg");
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

.TheBtn {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 4.4vw;
  width: 22.2vw;
  left: 19vw;
  top: 10.8vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="TheBtn"></button>
    </div>
</body>
```

I have also for testing purposes changed the min-height of the div to 100vh, that way it will span the whole height of the screen.

Comment: This works thank you! One question though, why does adding a <label>Hi</label> under that div break the button's position?

Comment: It's because it changes the width of the div. If you run the code snippet above and look at the dimensions of the div it's 638px(width) x 220px(height). When you add the span it changes the width of the div to 621px because it forces the scroll bar to appear. If you set with width of HTML and Body to 100% and add overflow-x:hidden; it forces the content to be within the dimension of the screen. It also looks like you have to set the width of the div to 100vw.

Comment: Ah thank you very much! Your help saved me a lot of trouble!! :)

Comment: No problem! This stuff isn't easy and when you come to this site for assistance and to learn it shouldn't be met with attitudes and aggression. Some of the people on here are just plain rude. If you have any other questions feel free and i'll do my best to help you out!

Comment: Would you mind trying to help my out with this other problem of mine? It is sort of related to this post as well so I feel like you might have the expert skills to help me out :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48865820/html-css-positions-not-working/48870271?noredirect=1#comment84744466_48870271