# HTML Css Positions Not Working

Tags: html, css

Why are my buttons not staying in the correct positions when the window get resized? As far as I understand it it should work.

In my previous post I figured out how to correctly position things for window resizing ([CSS Top Relative To Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48767607/css-top-relative-to-screen/48770307?noredirect=1#comment84665820_48770307)), but using two divs seems to not work.

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.Div1 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/7NQ3IOt.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 76.1vw;
}

.Div2 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/CjVMSqG.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 169vw;
}

.Btns {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.1vw;
    left: 16.5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Div1">
        <button class="Btns" style="margin-top: 4.8%">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Div2">
        <button class="Btns" style="margin-top: 4%">Button 2</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Again can u explain more?

Comment: @SagarKodte The buttons should stay exactly on the background image points when the user manually resizes the browser

Comment: I guess button is on same position.

Comment: `left: 16.5vw` is a bit wrong for me, if I write `17.8vw` the buttons fall right inside the rectangles

Comment: @JeremyThille But now resize the window and see how it not longer fits

Comment: I did, and it fits

Comment: It's still unclear how your code is not working as expected. You mean the second button (confusingly named Button 1 like the first) should remain off-screen on screen resizing?

Comment: @TylerH My bad, fixed the button name. Basically button 1 needs to stay exactly in the button 1 background box. Button 2 needs to stay exactly in the button 2 background box. While resizing the window of course...bare in mind even slight changes in their movements are wrong. These slight movements stack, and 20 divs later the buttons are waaaaay off

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:***

Hey let me know if this works for you:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}

.Div1 {
    background-image: url("http://imgur.com/7NQ3IOt.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 76.1vw;    
}

.Div2 {
    background-image: url("http://imgur.com/CjVMSqG.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    position: relative;
    height: 169vw;
}

.Btns {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2.1vw;   
    left: 17.8%;  
    width: 27%; 
}

.Div1 .Btns{
    height: 4.4%;
    top: 6%;
}

.Div2 .Btns{
    height: 1.9%;
    top: 2.3%;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Div1">
        <button class="Btns">Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="Div2">
        <button class="Btns">Button 2</button>
    </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: Your demo doesn't seem to work exactly. The buttons move upwards slightly. If you add a third and fourth div then the buttons would probably move way off (the problem stacks with each div you add)

Comment: Okay I just went back and made some adjustments. I think the issue is that the text size caused the height of the button to change sporadically. I went and defined the height of the buttons so that they should scale accordingly. I also test by adding more divs (doubled div1 and div2) and it seemed to resolve the issue. The only thing you will have to do is declare the height and top of the button separately for each div.